# Wait until get response in textbox c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am developing a chatbot to automate some work. When i type something on textbox and click on enter the text entered in the textbox will wait until it get processed. Normally it will take 10 to 20 seconds of time to process the function. But my question here is there a way for my bot to say please wait processing your request until it get response from function. how can i acheive this.

Comment: can you provide some "extra" code? :)

Comment: What UI technology are you using?  What attempt have you made?  Can you show a simple example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have tried it using WPF application. Now i kept progress bar in my xaml page. So it has to show the progress until it get response from the function. A string gets answer from a function. 
For eg: String a = getanswerfromfunction();
Getanswerfromfunction(); takes time to process it. So here the progressbar has to show the progress until it get reply from the function

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
fucn(){
    string text = textBox.Text;   //Saves the text from the Text Box
    textBox.Text = "Please wait!";   //Inserts "Please Wait!" into the Text Box
    textBox.ReadOnly = true;   //Makes it so the user can't edit the Text Box
    yourCode();
    textBox.Text = text;   //Re-inserts the text that was in the Text Box before
    textBox.ReadOnly = false;   //Makes it so the user can once again edit the Text Box
}
```

That should work!

Comment: Wiping out the original text and then restoring it when done processing after 10 to 20 seconds could be a bit disconcerting and confusing to the user.

Comment: then you could do. textBox.Text = string.Format("{0}.{1}Please Wait!", text, Enviroment.NewLine);

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But mycode doesn't support that. So i kept a progress bar in my page. So now i want my progress bar to show the progress until the function is processed. How can i achieve this?

Comment: With my limited knowledge on XAML, all I can say it that you can make your progress bar indeterminate. So apply something like: <ProgressBar x:Name = "pg2" Margin = "10" Height = "15" IsIndeterminate = "True" />

Comment: That's from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xaml/xaml_progressbar.htm BTW